# Export valid json from mongodb collection

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to export valid json from a mongodb collection I created using node and instagram's api. I must be missing something as it seems like it should be super simple. I've read other posts and mongo's documentation, specifically about mongoexport. 
My end goal is to build a d3 map. I used the basic mongoexport command from the documentation and it returned a json file in the following format:

```
{'name':'dan'}
{'name':'emma'}
```

**valid json would be:**

```
[{'name':'dan'},
{'name':'emma'}]
```

I know there are workarounds to this, even one as simple as finding '$' in sublime text which would go to the end of every line, and then could just add a coma. It would just be great to know the proper way technically of doing this. One post suggested using JSON.parse, so I tried this using fs.readFile but it returns the error:

```
undefined:2
{ "attribution" : null, "tags" : [], "location" : { "latitude" : 48.857141667,
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {.
```

I simply just need to export the entire mongo collection into a json file that's valid (would successfully pass http://jsonlint.com/ test).
 
Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: slightly confused, why are you using mongoexport instead of something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose to just get the result from mongo...?

Comment: I've used mongoose a bit, but always when using Express as well; never when just working with one file / trying to output a mongodb collection into a file. Would mongoose also help in that scenario? I looked through the documentation and it wasn't entirely clear to me. Are there any examples online you've seen I can use as a reference?

Answer (score 16):

using themongoexport util use --jsonArray

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, parsing the result of mongodump directly probably isn't a good idea. Mongo doesn't give you any guarantee that the elements in the dump will be a valid json (and they're not).

But if you're so inclined to do this you can use [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream) to read newline delimited stream of objects and a parser that allows your json to have single quotes instead of double quotes (i.e. [hanson](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hanson)).

Then your code might look something like this:

```
var es = require('event-stream'),
    hanson = require('hanson'),
    in = process.stdin,
    out = process.stdout;


in //read the input stream
    .pipe(es.split()) //split it on newline
    .pipe(es.map(function(data, cb) {
        if (data === '') { //necessary due to the last element produced by split
            cb();
        } else {
            cb(null, hanson.parse(data)); //parse the line with hanson
        }
    }))
    .pipe(es.writeArray(function (err, array){ //convert resulting objects to array
        var strArray = JSON.stringify(array);
        out.write(strArray + '\n'); //write the resulting array to output stream
    }));
```

If you had a stream of valid json objects (with double quotes), the same code would get shortened to:

```
var es = require('event-stream'),
    hanson = require('hanson'),
    in = process.stdin,
    out = process.stdout;


in
    .pipe(es.split()) 
    .pipe(es.parse())
    .pipe(es.writeArray(function (err, array){ 
        var strArray = JSON.stringify(array);
        out.write(strArray + '\n'); 
    }));
```

Skipped error handling for clarity.